# Unity Mirror can't reflect another mirror across from it

Tags: unity, reflection-rendering

I created a mirror in Unity using the FX/MirrorReflection and the script that comes with it.
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MirrorReflection4

One mirror at a time works perfectly fine, but as soon as I add another mirror in front of the other mirror it starts bugging out.

See image below for the result I'm getting.
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this so that both mirrors can reflect off each other?

Comment: I think you can make It easily : first make new reder texture then go to camera component and import your render texture then you should attach render texture to your object